# Acceder a Array de Objetos por indice

Tags: javascript, java, array, nashnorn

Al acceder a la información del backend que esta en java obtengo un array de linkedHashMap y con la funcion Array.forEach() lo recorro y el dato que leo es el siguiente:

`arrayDatos = [{codigo=GXXX0001, fecha=2020-08-01}, {codigo=GXXX0002, fecha=2020-08-03}]`

al acceder al objeto de la primera posición que es un linkedHashMap:

`{codigo=GXXX0001, fecha=2020-08-01}`

Obtengo sus valores de esta forma y me imprime correctamente:

```
arrayDatos[0].codigo
arrayDatos[0].fecha
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de acceder sin escribir el key(codigo, fecha); si no llamarlo por un numero de indice, algo parecido a esto:

```
objeto[0].[1]
objeto[0].[2]
```

Consideren que la información yo la obtengo y manipulo y lo esto haciendo con el motor de javascript para java nashorn que solo soporta ES5.

El backend esta en java y el dato que me devuelve es un array de linkedHashMap({codigo=GXXX0002, fecha=2020-08-03}), hecho mas o menos de la siguiente forma:

```
var system = java.lang.System

var LinkedHashMap = Java.type("java.util.LinkedHashMap")
var lhm = new LinkedHashMap()

lhm.put('key1', 'value1')
lhm.put('key2', 'value2')
lhm.put('key3', 'value3')

system.out.println(lhm.toString());
// prints: {key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}
```

Este tipo de dato se puede transformar a json? o un dato mas manipulable en javascript? ya que necesito recorrerlo en orden, no por su key ya que es lo que me piden, gracias por la ayuda.

Solucion:

```
// Este es un ejemplo de como lo solucione, el codigo no corre en un snippet pero en el Nashorn funciona.

// Este dato no lo entiendo, yo no lo genero haci me lo envia el backend, yo solo he puesto como me lo imprime en un console.log
var datosBackend = '[{codigo=GXXX0001, fecha=2020-08-01}, {codigo=GXXX0002, fecha=2020-08-03}]' // Entiendo que es un array de objetos

// Se puede iterar como array
datosBackend.forEach(function(datos){
    console.log(datos) 
    // Imprime cada objeto en el array.
    // {codigo=GXXX0001, fecha=2020-08-01}
    // {codigo=GXXX0002, fecha=2020-08-03}
    
    // Se puede iterar los elementos
    for (var objeto of datos) {
    console.log("Key: " + objeto[0] + "/ valor: " + objeto[1])
        // Imprime el Key y Valor.
        // Key: codigo / valor: GXXX0001
        // Key: fecha / valor: 2020-08-01
        // Key: codigo / valor: GXXX0002
        // Key: fecha / valor: 2020-08-03
    }
});
```

El código funciona pero como programador para mi es muy importante entender el funcionamiento del mismo, así que alguien tiene alguna idea se lo agradecería.

Comment: Por otro lado el dato: {codigo=GXXX0001, fecha=2020-08-01} no se reconoce bien o no entiendo bien que clase de dato es, con el typeof me dice que es un objeto pero al tratar de acceder a el como objeto me salen errores.

Comment: La notación `{codigo=GXXX0001, fecha=2020-08-01}` es errónea. Los objetos son pares de `clave: valor` separados por el símbolo `:`. Tu lo tienes con el símbolo `=`. Revisa eso primero.

Comment: Para mi lo extraño es que al acceder al objeto con la funcion Array.forEach(), si me deja recorrerlo:

`código`
v_va_resqry.result.forEach(function(rs){

        console.log(rs.fecha);
        console.log(rs.codigo);
    });
rs es este valor : [{codigo=GXXX0001, fecha=2020-08-01}, {codigo=GXXX0002, fecha=2020-08-03}]
`código`

Comment: El codigo que muestras produce errores. Incluso esto: `fecha=2020-08-01` no tiene sentido. Algo estás omitiendo, porque ya te digo que lo que muestras no es un objeto válido en JS. ¿Puedes poner un snippet con el código real de lo que tienes? Puedes leer [mcve].

Comment: Si disculpas, ahora entendí cual era el dato que estaba leyendo es un linkedHashMap, use: Object.prototype.toString.call() para obtener el tipo de dato y me salio: [object java.util.LinkedHashMap]

Comment: Javascript no tiene nada que ver con Java, por favor elimina la etiqueta de Javascript de tu pregunta. Todos los comentarios y la respuesta están basados en Javascript.

Comment: @MauricioContreras aunque es verdad que JavaScript y Java son lenguajes diferentes, OP ha mencionado que usa nashorn, que es un motor de JavaScropt que se ejecuta en una máquina virtual de Java, de hecho el mapa lo está generando con JavaScript. También he borrado mi respuesta ya que contesté antes de que se aclarase que está trabajando con nashorn.

Comment: Ok, si, ya veo que es eso. Igual no había leído toda su edición, solo leí su respuesta en comentario. XD

Comment: @Trauma si no te importa voy a revertir la edición de etiquetas para que contenga la etiqueta JavaScript otra vez, ya que OP ha especificado que usa nashorn, que es un motor de JavaScript para Java, por lo que la etiqueta tiene relevancia.

Comment: @ordago Ok, aunque no estoy muy seguro. Entiendo que el problema ha de estar en 1 de las 2 partes, o en la de Java o en la de JavaScript.

Comment: No acabo de entender el escenario, pero no se puede hacer un JSON.stringify o similar de un objeto Java porque lanzará una excepción. Lo que puedes hacer es transformar a JSON **ANTES** de pasarlo como variable al scriptEngine

Comment: A ver si esto sirve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166592/convert-normal-java-array-or-arraylist-to-json-array-in-android

Comment: Gracias a todos, encontré una solución y la puse en el post, aunque solo funciona en el compilador de JS del Nashorn.